# Are compilers able to avoid branching instructions?

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation, c++14, micro-optimization

I've been reading about [bit twiddling hacks](http://www.graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) and thought, are compilers able to avoid branching in the following code:

```
constexpr int min(const int lhs, const int rhs) noexcept {
    if (lhs < rhs) {
        return lhs;
    }
    return rhs
}
```

by replacing it with ([explanation](http://www.graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax)):

```
constexpr int min(const int lhs, const int rhs) noexcept {
    return rhs ^ ((lhs ^ rhs) & -(lhs < rhs));
}
```

Comment: You have a `constexpr` there anyway

Comment: If any of `lhs` and `rhs` is not a constant it will have to be evaluated

Comment: Are you sure this is faster?

Comment: It may be faster on some processors, you can read more if you follow the link with explanation.

Comment: The comment says that there is a slight possibility that it might rarely be faster on some uncommon processors. Why should a compiler care?

Comment: If you look at the item "Merge bits from two values according to a mask" on the same page, that's a transformation that gcc does (clang as well IIRC).

Comment: We may point particular `cpu-type` to the compiler, e.g. `-mtune=cpu-type`, I think it's pretty reasonable to optimize code for target CPU. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The guys writing the compilers read about the bithacks tricks decades ago. The compilers' optimizers already know all about this.

Comment: FWIW, most compilers on most platforms will do something better than either of the implementations naively suggest, using a conditional move.

Comment: I understand that this tricks are old :) I think I should have asked question differently: «Should I use this tricks to gain some performance or should I rely on the compiler and write readable code?».

Comment: What's `x` and `y` in the second code example?

Comment: Kostya Bazhanov, it is uncertain if you gain performance or just confuse the compiler and hinder him doing some better optimization. And if there ever is a bug somewhere in the application, anyone trying to find it will be confused to what your code exactly does, and should you mistype even 1 letter in your formula, your bug will never be found. Readable code is the priority. If your application has performance issues, benchmark where your cpu time is spend and optimize whatever takes up most of that time. Buying more computation power/time is cheap/easy.

Comment: Hmm, there's an elephant in the room.  A sane compiler writer will strongly avoid introducing the kind of threading race bug that bithack is apt to trigger.

Comment: @HansPassant What "threading race bug" are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clang++` (3.5.2-1) seems to be smart enough `-O3` (I'm not using c++11 or c++14, `constexpr` and `noexcept` removed from source):

```
08048760 <_Z3minii>:
 8048760:   8b 44 24 08             mov    0x8(%esp),%eax
 8048764:   8b 4c 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 8048768:   39 c1                   cmp    %eax,%ecx
 804876a:   0f 4e c1                cmovle %ecx,%eax
 804876d:   c3                      ret
```

`gcc` (4.9.3) (`-O3`) instead do branch with `jle`:

```
08048740 <_Z3minii>:
 8048740:       8b 54 24 08             mov    0x8(%esp),%edx
 8048744:       8b 44 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%eax
 8048748:       39 d0                   cmp    %edx,%eax
 804874a:       7e 02                   jle    804874e <_Z3minii+0xe>
 804874c:       89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
 804874e:       f3 c3                   repz ret
```

(x86 32bit)

This `min2` (mangled) is the *bit* alternative (from `gcc`):

```
08048750 <_Z4min2ii>:
 8048750:       8b 44 24 08             mov    0x8(%esp),%eax
 8048754:       8b 54 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%edx
 8048758:       31 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
 804875a:       39 c2                   cmp    %eax,%edx
 804875c:       0f 9c c1                setl   %cl
 804875f:       31 c2                   xor    %eax,%edx
 8048761:       f7 d9                   neg    %ecx
 8048763:       21 ca                   and    %ecx,%edx
 8048765:       31 d0                   xor    %edx,%eax
 8048767:       c3                      ret
```

Comment: Clangs output does omit the branch, but it doesn't change it to the xor in the OP's example.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode no it doesn't, but looking at the dump, it does even better, let me add the dump of the other function, I think currently clang solution looks the most simple and elegant, how do you think?

Comment: Thanks for providing some hard data.

Comment: @Mike, sometime checking is faster than asking (`objdump -S` *may* be your friend), it should answer the OP though, not only some compiler already does, but it does in a better way. I hope for the OP the question was theoretical and he isn't having real troubles with branches.

Comment: I get `cmovg` with GCC, unless I target older processors that don't have that instruction (`-march=i586` or lower). How is your GCC configured?

Comment: @hvd default from Debian on i686 using only `-O3`. My point is not proving `clang` is better than `gcc`, I'm pretty sure it can already do better with options, on other arch, or will in a near future.

Comment: @Alex I'm not passing any special options either, that's why I commented. The default on a compiler configured for i686 should use the conditional move, and that's exactly what I get with Fedora's GCC (5.1.1), as well as with a custom-built GCC (4.9.2).

Comment: @hvd [version and dumpspecs](http://pastebin.com/5P1N8KRA). And [configure](http://pastebin.com/jQ8Mnd9r). You were right, while the system is i686 the toolchain seems to be i586

Comment: @Alex And Debian's website even refers to it as i386. :) That explains the difference. clang doesn't care (or is configured to not care) about i586, so it can use instructions not available on it.

Comment: @hvd surely so, gonna rebuild the toolchain now :)

Answer (score 8):

- **Are compilers able to...**: Yes definitively!
- **Can I rely on those optimizations?**: No, you can't rely on any optimization. There may always be some strange conditions under which a compiler chooses not to implement a certain optimization for some non-obvious reason or just fails to see the possibility. Also in general, I've made the observation that compilers sometimes are a lot dumber than people think (Or the people (including me) are dumber than they think).(1)
- Not asked, but a very important aspect: **Can I rely on this actually being an optimization?**  NO! For one, (especially on x86) performance always depends on the surrounding code and there are a lot of different optimizations that interact. Also, some architectures might even offer commands that implement the operation even more efficient.
- **Should I use bit twiddeling optimizations?**: In general: No - **especially not without verifying** that they actually give you any benefit! Even when they do improve performance, it makes your code harder to read and review and it makes some architecture and compiler specific assumptions (representation of integers, execution time of instructions, penalty for branch miss-prediction ...), that might lead to worse performance when you port your code to another architecture or - in the worst case even lead to false results.

My advice:
If you need to get the last bit of performance for a **specific system**, then just try both variants and measure (and verify the result every time, you update your CPU and/or compiler). For any other case, assume that the compiler is at least as good in making low level optimizations as you are. I'd also suggest that you first learn about all optimization related compiler flags and set up a proper benchmark BEFORE starting to use low level optimizations in any case.

I think the only area, where hand optimizations are still sometimes beneficial is if you want to to optimally use vector units. Modern compiler can auto-vectorize many things, but this is still relatively new field and there are certain things which the compiler is just not allowed to do because it violates some guarantees from the standard (especially where floating point operations are concerned).

(1) Some people seem to think, that independent of what their code looks like, the compiler will always produce the optimal code that provides the same semantics. For one, there are limits to what a compiler can do  in a limited amount of time (there are a lot of heuristics that work MOST of the time but not always). Second, in many cases, the c++ standard requires the compiler to give certain guarantees, that you are not actually interested in at the moment, but still prevent optimizations.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Can you elaborate a bit? Do you mean code space or data? It's been some time since I programmed on really memory constraint systems or when I had to care about every last bit of performance.

Comment: I mean data space, some systems are *very* limited on ram and every byte is a prisoner. e.g. using one `int` to store 32 `bool`s is good space efficiency.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: I agree, but storing data in a compact manner is not, what I'd personally call bit twiddeling. For me bit twiddelling means to replace some higher mathematical functions (multiplications, min/max, absolute value etc.) with a bunch of bit operations as in the OP's example.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: As far as saving space is concerned, it is my feeling that the number of systems, where you really have to worry about each byte becomes fewer and fewer, but on the other hand - especially on high performance systems - it is quite important that your data structures fit into the cache or a cache line. And of course, if you have to store millions or billions of entries, every bit counts anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for a compiler to detect this pattern and replace it by your proposal.

However, neither clang++ nor g++ do this optimization, see for instance [g++ 5.2.0's assembly output](https://gcc.godbolt.org).